# bash- How to check if number of arguments exceed a certain number?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if the number of arguments in my bash script exceeds the number 2, and exit with a non-zero exit status, but I keep getting the following error :

```
unexpected token `newline', conditional binary operator expected
```

This is my code:

```
if [[ #$ > 2 ]]
then
    echo "error" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This is very simple, but I can't figure out why I get this error. Am I not supposed to use double brackets in the if statement?

Comment: You have a typo; #$ should be $#. Also, I think for integer comparison it should be `-gt`, not >.

Comment: If you changed `#$` to `$#` your test would work -- try it. However, sputnick's placing of the test inside the arithmetic operators insures a numerical test and will work as well.

Comment: yeah, the typo was messing me up, dumb mistake. But I noticed that this works if I use double square brackets or double round brackets, does it really matter which I use? I know round brackets are for arithmetic operators, but this piece of code works both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (( $# > 2 ))
then
    echo "error" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Like greybot said on irc://irc.freenode.org/#bash : *the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. There's a reason it isn't in the topic*

Comment: Oh I see... stupid mistake on my part. I'll accept this answer in a sec, but if you don't mind, could you tell me how I could make error echo only to stderr and not stdout.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html):

```
if (( $# > 2 )) 
then
    echo "error" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Stop giving bad sources to learn shell. TLDP is not recommended. See 'bash faq' & 'bash hackers' instead. As greybot said on irc://irc.freenode.org/#bash _the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. There's a reason it isn't in the topic_

Comment: Not recommended by whom?

Comment: Just because something is outdated doesn't necessarily mean one can't still get useful information from it. I also am not someone who would ever say one thing is 100% right or wrong — there's always room for uncertainty in almost anything.

Comment: If you want to learn deprecated expressions, it's your choice. Just reading the fisrt lines of your link is scary in 2014 `z=`expr $z + 3``

Comment: In the computing field there are those that believe one needs to do things in particular ways, but unless something inherently fails or is done inefficiently there's really no limits to what you might be able to take from deprecated info that might seem quite archaic. And my answer really has nothing to do with your example; go up a few lines in the docs and then tell me what's wrong with it.

Comment: Using `let` =) The arithmetic compound command should almost always be preferred. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let

Comment: My answer has nothing about 'let' in it though. btw - thanks for the wiki link - bookmarked.

Comment: I never said something about your code, but about the link. Don't take it personally

Comment: No worries, and no offense taken. I don't mind hearing your arguments - I always try to see the big picture. And of course there are always going to be situations where one method is preferred over the other... that's coding :)